# Call method on object from different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, object

I inherited a iOS app from 2009. I am currently in the process of creating a new UI for it. In one of the view controllers, I have a UITableView.

In the old version of the app, some of the required table view methods are implemented like so:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Methods


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SpeciesCell";

    SpeciesCell* speciesCell = (SpeciesCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!speciesCell) 
    {
        speciesCell = [[[SpeciesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        speciesCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, ROW_HEIGHT);
    }

    [speciesCell setDrawShortSeparator];

    Species *theSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [speciesCell setSpecies:theSpecies usingImageType:currentImageType sortBy:sortBySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];

    return speciesCell;
}
```

(The above code works just fine for the current UI of the app.)

I tried putting the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in my new view controller. Unfortunately, I keep getting `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell setDrawShortSeparator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. This error of course means that I'm a method on an object that doesn't respond to that method.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "Species.h"
#import "SpeciesTableViewCell.h"
#import "SpeciesCell.h"
/*#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "BrowseHelpViewController.h"
#import "Species.h"
*/

@interface SecondViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{

}

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pear.png"];
    _left_button.tag = 1;
    [_left_button setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_search_bar sizeToFit];
    [self fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex];

}
/* other methods */

#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource Methods

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    //NSLog(@"number of rows %lu", (unsigned long)[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SpeciesCell";

    SpeciesCell* speciesCell = (SpeciesCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!speciesCell)
    {
        speciesCell = [[[SpeciesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        speciesCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, ROW_HEIGHT);
    }

    [speciesCell setDrawShortSeparator];

    Species *theSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [speciesCell setSpecies:theSpecies usingImageType:currentImageType sortBy:sortBySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];

    return speciesCell;
} 
@end
```

However, I am not calling the `setDrawShortSeparator` method on a UITableViewCell object - I'm calling it on `speciesCell`, which is an object of the `SpeciesCell` class. At the top of my ViewController, I import `SpeciesCell.h`.

I would appreciate all insight! Thank you.

Comment: Show your code that doesn't work, not the old working code

Comment: `SpeciesCell`: How is it registered? Do you have a xib? A cell in the storyboard? If yes, the class isn't correctly set.

Comment: @Larme thank you! I customized the class for the `UITableViewCell` in storyboard - that fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find the file that contains the view** for that cell and set its class to be your **SpeciesCell** class. also if you are using any **IBOutlets** you should connect them too.